# Is $g(x)=O(2^x) ?$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Consider the functions $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ defined by $g(x) = 4^x$.

Show whether $g(x) = O(2^x)$

Any hints? i don't know how to go ahead with this questions?

I know that $g(x) \leq M|h(x)|$ such that $x \geq x_0$

Comment: What is $x_0$ in this case.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima is it 2?

Answer (score 2):

A function $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ if there exists some positive real $c$ such that $f(x) \leq cg(x)$ for all $x \geq x_0$.

So $4^x \leq c 2^x$ becomes $2^x \leq c$, which is only true for $x \leq \log_2(c)$.

So this means $4^x$ is not $O(2^x)$, since any $x_0 > \log_2(c)$ would make the inequality fail.

Comment: @User1911 Please consider adding a checkmark to this answer if you found it helpful -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Definition**: A function $g(x)$ is $\mathcal{O}(f(x)$ iff there exists some $x_0, M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \geq x_0$ we have $|g(x)| \leq M |h(x)|$

$g(x) = 4^x = 2^x \cdot 2^x = 2^x \cdot h(x)$, so our choice of $M$ would need to always be larger than $2^x$, impossible for a constant. Therefore $g(x)$ is not $\mathcal{O}(2^x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {4^x}{2^x}=+\infty$$

thus $$4^x\neq O (2^x)\;\; (x\to +\infty) $$

because
$x\mapsto \frac {4^x}{2^x}$ is not bounded near $+\infty $.

Comment: I'm fairly confident OP is looking for the limiting behaviour as $g(x) \rightarrow \infty$, not the behaviour near 2.

Comment: I asked him and he told that $x_0=2$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Thanks. I am was confused with $x_0$ apologies i am still learning.